# Passing large data to module (node.js/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two `Node` projects:

- `npm package` - accepts `json` object and based its content executes/communicates with third party `REST API`
- `CLI tool` - reading an config file (`yaml`), convert it to json, require the `npm package` and pass the generated `json` file

Some of the `REST API` endpoints are accepting file uploads (**file size can be anything from few `kB` to few `GB`**). At the moment the `npm package` is using `fs` module to read the content of the file(s) and upload them.

The future plan, for the `npm package`, is to be used inside the browser (UI version of the `CLI tool`) and I want to loose the `fs` dependency.

Was thinking to read the required files from the `CLI tool` and pass them inside the `json` file to the `npm package`. This will, probably, work fine for the smaller files. But dont think is suitable solution for the larger files.

Any advice how to pass large data to the `npm package` in this scenario without reading the file from the `npm package` itself?

Comment: `Was thinking to read the required files from the CLI tool and pass them inside the json file to the npm package.` if you UI can communicate with the _"CLI tool"_ then why can't you instruct the _"CLI tool"_ to send that file directly? Why do you want to pass the file from the _"CLI tool"_ to the web UI to then pass it from there to the REST API?

Comment: The CLI and UI will be a separate projects and they will not be able to communicate between each other

Comment: `and I want to loose the fs dependency` and how do you (plan to) get the data you want to pass to the REST API in the UI version?

Comment: In the UI the user will pick the files for upload and then pass it to the module to upload

Comment: But why do you think that you need `fs`? You get the data from the selected file (using the file API of the Web UI), call the corresponding function of the module and pass the data as an argument to the function. (the same can be done in the CLI, there is no need for an intermediate file)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

I know that at least on the browser side they are widely use to pass file content (for example when user picks a file to upload) and I'm fairly sure you find them on Node.js side. They could work in a lazy manner, so actual file reading could be done as you process the data.